# Switch css class dynamically on HREF click

Tags: jquery, css, c#-4.0

My task is to click an HREF list item, make it bold and make the others normal. Todo this I need to execute a simple class switch. I current get no errors at inspect, it just does nothing. Do server tags (asp:hyperlink which equates to a href) make a difference? Here's my code...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SmuSideNavigationSublayout.ascx.cs" Inherits="SmuSideNavigation.layouts.ProjectX.sublayouts.SmuSideNavigationSublayout" %>

<style type="text/css">

    .selected_Turn {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .selected_Turn_on {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>


<div id="smuSideNav" class="selTurn">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header home"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypParent" CssClass="selected_Turn"/></li>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypChild" CssClass="selected_Turn"/></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.selTurn a').click(function () {
        jQuery('.selTurn a').removeAttr('class'); // remove all classes
        jQuery(this).attr('class', this.className + "_on");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your CSS classes are not the same. In the ASP code you have your class name as being `selected_Turn` but in your jQuery you are selecting an element with the class of `selTurn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your anchors have the `selected_Turn` class. Just add a click handler to them, that will remove the `selected_Turn_on` from the others and add it to the clicked. The last added class will override the default `selected_Turn` class's `font-weight` property.

```
$('.selected_Turn').click(function () {
    $('.selected_Turn').removeClass('selected_Turn_on');
    $(this).addClass('selected_Turn_on');
});
```

Comment: ok, this works BUT just for a split second until the page loads again. On another topic, how do I persist this class through the page load?

Comment: JavaScript is client side. If you want to save these settings you have to store it somewhere. For example in a [cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/), or [local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/). Then read the value and make the changes according to that.

Answer (score 2):

You should try jquery addClass() toggleClass() and removeClass() methods instead of dealing with attributes.  I believe toggleClass() will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you first remove all the class attributes:
`jQuery('.selTurn a').removeAttr('class'); // remove all classes`

then you attempt to append to those class attributes:
`jQuery(this).attr('class', this.className + "_on");`

My guess would be somewhere to do with what is happening to `this` in your click function...